# Laravel 5.8 error SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 uuid

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am using Laravel 5.8 and package ["goldspecdigital/laravel-eloquent-uuid"](https://github.com/goldspecdigital/laravel-eloquent-uuid) because I need to use UUID4 and here is my migration file:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            // $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('path');
            $table->uuid('visit_id');
            $table->foreign('visit_id')->references('id')->on('visits');

        });
    }
```

I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `doctors
>   _pharmacy`.`images` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `images`
>    add constraint `images_visit_id_foreign` foreign key (`visit_id`) references `visits` (`id`))

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Update the `schema` for `visits` and `images` as follows.
Then run `php artisan migrate` cmd.

`visits` table schema

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('visits', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();
            // your column will be here
            ......
            ......
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

`images` table schema

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('path');
        $table->uuid('visit_id');
        $table->foreign('visit_id')->references('id')->on('visits');

    });
}
```